# get the result of select query with different database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have declared two databases in my database.php, how i can access the users list  of db and db2 instances

```
        //database initialisation 
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->db1 = $CI->load->database('default', TRUE);
        $CI->db2 = $CI->load->database('stylior_db', TRUE);
         //select query for db2
    $this->$db2->from('users');
    // $this->$CI->db2->where('id',1312);

    $query = $this->$CI->db2->get();
    print_r($query);

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row;
    }
```

Comment: write two times same query.

Comment: You have created instance of database, so no need to use $this keyword to get results. just use $query = $CI->db1->get('users') and $query1 = $CI->db2->get('users')

Comment: not getting the result from above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
    $db_result = $this->db->get("table_users"); // here default database connected
    $this->db1 = $this->load->database('db1', TRUE);    
    $db1_result = $this->db1->get("table_users")
```

Comment: could you please explore it with one select query example.

Comment: I just did it in $db_result and $db1_result variable in  my answer. check it

Comment: modify your answer for select query database connection is working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use $this keyword directly to get you result. You can use following code to get results:

```
//database initialisation 
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $this->db1 = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        $this->db2 = $this->load->database('stylior_db', TRUE);
         //select query for db2
    $this->$db2->from('users');
    // $this->db2->where('id',1312);

    $query = $this->db2->get();
    print_r($query);

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row;
    }
```